# Sending to a serial device via socat only shows up if I'm actively reading -- I need the data to be cached

Tags: linux, serial-port, socat

I have socat creating two serial ports: `ttyclient` and `ttyserver`, ttyclient will be called by an application and I have a script listening to ttyserver. The sequence of events I need is

1. My socat creates the two via `/usr/bin/socat -d -d PTY,link=./ttyserver,raw,echo=0 PTY,link=./ttyclient,raw,echo=0`
2. My script writes a few bytes to `ttyserver` (to be read by `ttyclient`)
3. At some later point in time the application runs, reads the bytes from `ttyclient` and goes to work.

The problem I am having is the bytes are only readable if something is read *during* step 2. If I run `minicom -D ./ttyclient` before step 2 I see the bytes being transmitted as expected, but afterwards shows nothing. The data appears to be discarded.

Is this expected behavior? I'm unsure of how to keep the data around so when something reads it is presented with those bytes. Alternatively I'd happy if I had some way to know `ttyclient` has been opened and send data on that event.

Comment: Interesting, when I change in step 1 link=./ttydevice to link=./ttyserver I get the behaviour you want. Please use in step 1 options -d -d -d -d -lu and provide the output of a "failing" attempt!

Comment: That was a typo on my part, I was using ttyserver across the board. I'm not entirely clear on what's different now but this appears to work. I think I was using minicom so it was reading new data but was not showing me data left, cat however does. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that I was using Minicom to read `ttyclient`. For whatever reason Minicom won't display cached data like that... If I just use `cat` I get my desired behavior.